# What is the unit of the correlation function between logarithmically rebinned galaxy spectrum and stellar template spectrum?

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, spectra, units

Assume I have a logarithmically rebinned galactic spectrum $G(x)$ and a stellar template spectrum $S(x)$, where $x = \ln{\lambda}$. When $[\lambda] = 1 Å$, then $[x] = 1 Np/Å$. The fourier transformed galaxy spectrum is $\tilde{G}(\kappa)$, then $[\kappa]= 1/(Np/Å)$.

Now the correlation function between galaxy and spectra is defined as:
$K_{S, G}(z)= \int dx G(x+z)S(x)$, so the unit of $z$ should be $[z] = [x]= 1 Np/Å $?
Since the rebinning on a logarithmic wavelength scale introduces an easy conversion from measured wavelength shifts to velocity shifts: $\Delta x = \Delta \lambda/\lambda=\Delta v/c$. So the way $K_{S,G}(z)$ is defined above it measures shifts in wavelengths between the spectra. For my analysis, I needed a velocity axis, so I plotted my correlation function on a velocity axis (which would be wrong to label with Np/Å), at the same time I just wonder how to do this consistently in the mathematical formalism. One would have to do something like $\bar{K}_{S,G}(v) \equiv K_{S,G}(v/c)$ ?

And then one would need a different variable in fourier space: $\tilde{\bar{K}}_{S, G}(\bar{\kappa})$, where $\bar{\kappa} = 1 s/km$, when $[v] =1 km/s$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit is that of a velocity. If you have bins of equal $\ln \lambda$ (which equals $\Delta \lambda/\lambda =\Delta v/c$), then each of your pixels (in your spectrum and in the template) *represents* a constant velocity increment $\Delta v = c |\Delta \ln \lambda|$, which could have units of km/s.

The shift in the peak of a cross-correlation function is known as "the lag" and the velocity shift is given by the lag (in pixels) multiplied by $\Delta v$.

Comment: Makes sense, but what do I need to change in the formula to make it consistent. Because looking at the formula that I gave for the cross-correlation function the function argument of the galaxy spectrum$(x+z)$ inside the integral needs to have the same units.

Comment: assuming that the unit i gave for x is correct of course.

Comment: @trynerror I don;t understand your comment. The x-axes of both spectrum and template need to be the same. The cross correlation is a function of $z$, which is the lag in pixels.

Comment: When I write $K_{S, G}(z)= \int dx G(x+z)S(x)$, then the units of x and z should be the same formally ? I understand your answer and it makes sense, I guess the remaining doubt is more about this formula.

Comment: So if z is the lag in pixels, and 1 pixel has the unit 1 Np/Å, then the velocity shift would be of units 1 Np/Å * km/s ?

Comment: @trynerror I don't know what Np per Angstrom means. If you have binned in equal steps of $\ln \lambda$ then the pixels have units of fractions of the speed of light.

Comment: If $[\lambda] = 1 Å$ and $x = \ln{\lambda}$ then $[x]=1 Np/Å,$  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neper). If I read your last comment correctly x (the pixels)  have unit $[x] = [1/c] = 1 s/km$ for $[c] = 1 km/s$ I just would like all the units written out for the equations I used in the question.

Comment: @trynerror please define all your notation and abbreviations in your question. I can't understand any of this.

Comment: I don't know what variables you are refering to exactly,  I gave the formulas and units of all variables I use in these brackets [] in the question. Could you please explain why the unit of pixels is fractions of the speed of light, when binned in equal steps of $\ln{\lambda}$?

Comment: Neper ($1 NP$) is just the unit convention when using the natural logarithm. When variable $a$ has unit $1 b$, then the natural logarithm $\ln a$ has unit $1 Np/b$ .